# Adding Client Certifcate to Service Fabric

Tags: azure, service, certificate, client

I'm quite new to `Azure` and `Service Fabric`, I did a secure configuration of `Service Fabric` on `Azure Portal`, using a self signed certificate.
I'm having some trouble when trying to add a Client Certificate to it.
On the security (`service fabric cluster`) tab I am clicking Add button, choosing "Admin client" and then adding Certificate thumbprint.

After I got this error message:

> Failed to submit updates for certificate
>   .

What I missing?!

I looked for a solution in the  Documentation and googled, but no luck.

Could you advise?

Comment: I know it's an old post, but did you ever find out what was wrong there?

Comment: no, I did not find out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried to create different certificates as well as a new Fabric Service cluster from scratch and I got no progress.

I checked the browser log, and find out that the request response to the portal from the Fabric API is 400 BAD REQUEST!

Checking the Service Fabric cluster activity log, I found that this write operation failed and checking the JSON response is saying that the certificate failed to pass multiple validation checks from the Fabric API side! Which is weird because this certificate was created by the Azure Key Vault and added to the Fabric cluster, all using the Azure Portal.

I submitted a support ticket and the response after the investigation is that it's a Fabric problem and they are rolling out a new update.

I'm trying now to add the same Client Certificate that was failing before to the same Fabric cluster and the error message didn't show up, and the cluster now is updating.