# Cannot add Admin Client key to Service Fabric cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-authentication

I am trying to add an Admin Client authentication key to my Service Fabric cluster created using the portal.
[image]

I keep getting this error (Failed to submit updates to 'admin client certificate' for cluster)- 
[image: Failed to submit updates for certificate]

The background - I cannot access the Service Fabric explorer after creating a cluster. I am guessing that this is because I don't have an admin client authentication set up yet.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Similar - old, unanswered question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044813/adding-client-certifcate-to-service-fabric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience with Azure Service Fabric Cluster you need to have the certificate added to add client certificate.  But if you set it up right should connect to it without setting new creds.

Steps below.

While setting up the cluster if its for testing you can use a self-signed certificate from Key Vault, the process can create one for you.

[image]

At the summary page of the Cluster setup you will get a link to obtain certificate as you will need that to access Fabric Cluster.

[image]

Make sure you download and install certificate (pfx) to computer's store.  No password is needed.

[image]

Once the Service Fabric cluster is fully deployed click on the 'Explorer' button or the link to open portal.  ***Make sure you are on IE or Edge because Chrome or Firefox will not like the self-signed certificate***

[image]

The browser should trigger an authentication, please select the certificate we installed previous.  If that is not showing as default use the more option to find it.  If it's not on the list it means that certificate was not install.

[image]

That should authenticate you and give you access to the Service Fabric Cluster.

[image]

Hope this information was helpful.

Comment: Maybe, that was a temporary Azure problem since I was able to add an Admin certificate the next day. I was able to see the service fabric explorer. I am still not able to access my application running on port 87xx even though I am able to run that after connecting to the node using RDP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the SF provision is not undergoing updates first.

Also you cannot access the SF management console with the cert that was used to secure the cluster.  You will need to generate a self-signed (unless you already have a CA cert) cert and use the thumbprint from that cert to import into the "Admin Client" in SF security section

This is the cert you need to also import to your client machine Cert repository